# How to get full Json from "referenced" document ID

Tags: java, json, mongodb, reference, morphia

im using @Reference to get all the information i need:

Morphia:

```
Query<Usuario> query = INSTANCE.createQuery(User.class);
    return query.asList();
```

and this return me:

```
{"users":[{"id":"53c5dc31278cbc6f862d8556","username":"MyUserName","password":"1","person":{"id":"53c5dc31278cbc6f862d8555","name":"My Name is"..rest of attrs from person..
```

for me this seems to be perfectly, very easy to get all the information about something

BUT the documentation from MongoDB say us to use in first case the normal reference, just add the referenced document id to the first one, ex:

MongoDB Documentation:

```
public class User {

@Id ObjectId id;
String username;
String password;
String personId; //or the ObjectId personId
}

public class Person {
@Id ObjectId id;
String name;
..
}
```

and this will return something like:

```
{"users":[{"id":"53c5dc31278cbc6f862d8556","username":"MyUserName","password":"1","personId":"53c5dc31278cbc6f862d8555"}]}
```

how can return all the json of the person in the place of personId like first example, if i use in this way i have to change the view too, in the first example i just need to show the result in the view using something like user.person.name

and why queries using @Reference and normal reference using the person id can be different?

since both will do 2 queries ??!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you store is the id of the Person, that's all you're going to get back.  If you want a full Person object in your User object return, you need to have a Person field in your User object and annotate it with `@Reference`.  Morphia will then load your User object and then do another query to load the Person object referenced.  But note that this does lead to two different queries so performance might be an issue if you're doing a lot of loads of User objects.

Comment: Hummm, i got it, just a last question, in a scenario of 1000 queries with reference, this can be a "issue" of queries? Or when you talk about lot of loads u mean 1million or more

Comment: With 1000, you're not likely to notice (though you might...) but with millions you'll definitely feel that hit.  You can pass lazy=true to the `@Reference` annotation to defer that load until you actually call `getPerson()` and that will at least spread out the additional queries over time and lessen the intial load time of your User objects.

Comment: yes, but i see no diference between the "automatic query" from the @Reference, and the manual query using the id of the person, will be 2 queries anyway

Comment: Yes, it will be two queries either way.  `@Reference` just automates that a bit for you.

Comment: so there is not many positive points in normal reference, if i use the @Reference and Lazy Load, will be the same as normal reference, correctly?

Comment: the only difference between using a lazy Reference and non-lazy one is that your User class will finish loading without loading any of the lazily referenced classes.

Comment: ok, thanks, i will stay using reference until i see any problem